# Cannot compile minimal app using npm link to reach external library

Tags: angular, npm

I've tried to set up a simple component library to be consumed by an application, and use npm link to connect them but it wont even compile and I'm not sure what I left out.  It's minimal, just to prove the method works.

I created a library using

1. ng new lib-test1 --create-application=false
2. cd lib-test1
3. ng generate library  TestLibrary1
4. ng build

I then create the application to test it using:

1. ng new app-test1
2. cd app-test1
3. ng build

the problem seems to be when I use npm link

1. cd to lib-test1/dist/test-library1> npm link
2. cd to app-test1> npm link test-library1

Add imports:

1. in app-test1/app.component.ts add "import {TestLibrary1Component} from 'test-library1';"
2. in app-test1/app.module.ts add import {TestLibrary1Component} from 'test-library1';
3. in app-test1/app.module.ts add TestLibrary1Component to the imports section
4. in app-test1/app.component.html add a tag to reference

ng build fails with the following:

√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Error: node_modules/test-library1/lib/test-library1.component.d.ts:3:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (test-library1) which declares TestLibrary1Component has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

3 export declare class TestLibrary1Component implements OnInit {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

It appears the link is not correctly functioning.
I tried "preserveSymLinks" : true in tsconfig.json both in compilerOptions as well as angularCompilerOptions, but it didnt help.
Nearly all the search results I've found on this issue are where it succesfully compiles but has a problem at run time.

I also tried an ivy friendly build according to this https://dev.to/dontry/using-npm-link-in-angular9-11ie but it had no effect either

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was in my imports, I was importing TestLibrary1Component instead of TestLibrary1Module